# Background task in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, backgroundworker, session-state

I am writing a web application using ASP.NET (not MVC), with .NET v4 (not v4.5).

I fetch some of the data which I must display from a 3rd-party web service, one of whose methods takes a long time (several seconds) to complete. The information to be fetched/prefetched varies depending on the users' initial requests (because different users ask for details about different objects).

In a single-user desktop application, I might:

- Display my UI as quickly as possible
- Have a non-UI background task to fetch the information in advance
- Therefore hope have an already-fetched/cached version of the data, by the time the user drills down into the UI to request it

To do something similar using ASP.NET, I guessed I can:

- Use a BackgroundWorker, passing the Session instance as a parameter to the worker
- On completion of the worker's task, write fetched data to the Session
- If the user's request for data arrives before the task is complete, then block until it it has completed

Do you foresee problems, can you suggest improvements?

[There are other questions on StackOverflow about ASP.NET and background tasks, but these all seem to be about fetching and updating global application data, not session-specific data.]

Answer (score 1):

Why not use same discipline as in a desktop application:

1. Load the page without the data from the service ( = `Display my UI as quickly as possible`)
2. Fetch the service data using an ajax call (= `Have a non-UI background task to fetch the information in advance`)
3. this is actually the same, although you can show an animated gif indicating you are still in progress... (`Therefore hope have an already-fetched/cached version of the data, by the time the user drills down into the UI to request it`)

In order to post an example code it will be helpful to know if you are using jquery? plain javascript? something else? no javascript?

**Edit**
I am not sure if this was your plan but Another idea is to fetch the data on server side as well, and cache the data for future requests.
In this case the stages will be:

1. Get a request.
2. is the service data cached?
   2.a. **yes?** post page with full data.
   2.b. **no?** post page without service data.
    2.b.i. On server side fetch service data and cache it for future requests.
    2.b.ii. On client side fetch service data and cache it for current session.

**Edit 2:**
Bare in mind that the down side of this discipline is that in case the method you fetch the data changes, you will have to remember to modify it both on server and client side.

Comment: I'm currently using a little plain javascript and would/could use jquery. If I were using ajax, would happen if the user tries to navigate/drill down before the request is complete? For example, the top level page should say, immediately, "You have selected object 'ABC'; you can view details for its 'Foo', 'Bar', and 'Baz' components." and have some data (from a faster source) for the user to look at. As soon as I know they're interested in ABC I want to start to fetch slower data too, so that it's available by the time they click on any of the Foo/Bar/Baz components.

Comment: I'm currently using REST-like URLs, for example `http:example.com/Report.aspx?id=ABC` and `http:example.com/Report.aspx?id=ABC&sub=Foo`

Comment: using jQuery it is very easy to use the events and change what user can and cannot do. I think it is reasonable to show him a message / animated gif to inform him that it is in progress. Will this not work for you?

Comment: I don't understand an advantage of using Ajax. My first thought (which might be wrong/narrow-minded) was to store and use the data only on the server, to use/reuse when the user navigates e.g. from the Foo to the Bar component. The method that takes a long time is a single method which returns a 'catalog' or taxonomy which tells me what further data will be available for all (each and every) component. When a user selects any component the server must wait for the single ABC catalog fetch to complete, which tells me what data I may subsequently fetch for any/every component.

Comment: `I am not sure if this was your plan` -- My plan was to synchronously block the user's page request / thread for a component, if the catalog hasn't arrived yet, perhaps by getting the BackgroundWorker to set an EventWaitHandle or AutoResetEvent on which the user's premature Page_Load can wait.

Comment: I strongly recommend against it. If you do so, you depend on the 3rd party data to heavily and the request to your site might time out...

Comment: So the important thing is to use Ajax prevent the client from making the request, until the data is available? In other words I can fetch the data asynchronously, and store it only on the server when it arrives ... however I should use Ajax to tell the client that navigation is now possible, use javascript/jquery to block navigation until navigation can be successful, and use a session cookie to remember that navigation is already possible if the user subsequently re-visits the top-level page which includes the Ajax guard?

Comment: That sounds right. You don't have to use a cookie. If the data is there (from cache), you might be able to tell it is there because the html element will be populated/visible/any other way you want to implement it.

Comment: this might be a bit late in the conversation, but bare in mind that the down side of this discipline is that in case the method you fetch the data changes, you will have to remember to modify it both on server and client side.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35773/discussion-between-chrisw-and-avi-turner)